# What's the difference between "&" in this program

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Below is part of a C++ program:

```
Circle circle1, &circle2 = circle1, *p = &circle2;
```

I'm wondering what is the difference in between the two `&`s there? Thanks so much.

Comment: you didn't include any code

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first (use of `&`) is declaring a Circle reference and the latter is the *address-of* operator for obtaining the memory address of `circle2`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Circle circle1, &circle2 = circle1, *p = &circle2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Circle circle1;
Circle &circle2 = circle1;  // & is used to declare a reference variable
Circle *p = &circle2;       // & is used to take the address of circle2
```

Answer (score 1):

They have two very different meanings. Its easier to see if you split up the terms.

```
Circle circle1; // A Circle object

Circle& circle2 = circle1; // A Circle reference

Circle* p = &circle2; // A Circle pointer takes the address of a Circle object
```

In the second line you are declaring a *reference* to a `Circle`.

In the third line you are taking the *address of* a `Circle`.

So the second line is using `&` to declare a ***reference type***.

The third line is using `&` as the ***address of*** operator.